# Body not passing in for Python Requests Module

Tags: python, api

I've been working on trying to reverse engineer an API for a university cybersecurity project and at the point where I've been able to make some API calls via browser console but having issues moving to code. The body being passed here worked fine with console requests but doesn't seem to be being passed with the requests module. API token removed for obvious reasons but rest of the code is included. I know the auth is working as it does give an OK requests but empty json body in line with missing headers.

```
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

adress = "https://api.yikyak.com/pusher/auth/"
adress2 = "https://api.yikyak.com/graphql"


auth = "TOKEN"
headers = {
    "Location":"POINT(-86.9066714589362 40.42441553439984)",
    "Authorization":auth,
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B137 Safari/601.1'
    
}
data = {"operationName":"Feed","query":"query Feed($feedType: FeedType, $feedOrder: FeedOrder, $pageLimit: Int, $cursor: String, $point: FixedPointScalar) {\n  feed(\n    feedType: $feedType\n    feedOrder: $feedOrder\n    first: $pageLimit\n    after: $cursor\n    point: $point\n  ) {\n    typename\n    edges {\n      typename\n      node {\n        typename\n        id\n        videoId\n        videoPlaybackDashUrl\n        videoPlaybackHlsUrl\n        videoThumbnailUrl\n        videoState\n        text\n        userEmoji\n        userColor\n        secondaryUserColor\n        distance\n        geohash\n        interestAreas\n        createdAt\n        commentCount\n        voteCount\n        isIncognito\n        isMine\n        isReported\n        myVote\n      }\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      typename\n      endCursor\n      hasNextPage\n    }\n  }\n}","variables":{"cursor":NULL,"feedOrder":"NEW","feedType":"LOCAL","pageLimit":50,"point":"POINT(-86.90185546875 40.40771484375)"}}
s = requests.Session()
B_response = s.post(adress2, data=data, headers=headers)

print(B_response.request.body)
print(B_response.status_code)
print(B_response.json())
```

Comment: It might be helpful to investigate what exactly the browser is doing. For example, some endpoints might require a CSRF token to be included in headers, and this might be automated by the browser, but in `requests` you need to fetch it and add to headers yourself.

BTW are you sure the authorization type is API Key, and not. eg. Bearer Token? Because then the syntax is slightly different and the value would be f"Bearer {token}"

Another tactic I use is to get the request to work with Postman and go from there.

Comment: @MichałZawadzki thanks for that input, I am sure the authorization is a token (when I don’t include that I get a 403 and with it I get the 400 OK) I think you may be on to something with the CSRF token because looking at the app scraping it has that so I’ll investigate that route and try out postman as well.

Comment: what do you mean `"console requests"`? Maybe it adds something extra. What do you get with `respone.text`? Maybe it send some useful information.